# Angular material md-select open direction

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to use angular-material and specifically the `md-select` directive. In [their example](http://codepen.io/AviEt/pen/ONOqjO) the selection container opens up so it hides the selector and stretches both up and down as seen in these images

**Before opening the selector**:
[image]

**After opening the selector**:
[image]

I use it in the top of my screen and I would like the selection container to open down (like old-school drop-down lists). **So I'm trying to achieve something that looks like this: (just for clarification - I made this image using paint. It's not that I was able to make it happen)**

[image]

Here is a code pen with the real example: http://codepen.io/AviEt/pen/ONOqjO

Comment: Strictly speaking material design spec does not all this 

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-behavior

Comment: @Rishab777 - If I'm not mistaken, my request does not violate the spec. I do want it to appear on top of the emitting element but I want it to start from the top of the emitting element and not above it. If you look at the spec where it's written "The currently selected menu item appears over the emitting element.", the first item of the menu appears right on top of the emitting element and not above it. And that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: you've already got a working example. What was your question again?

Comment: @sdfacre - it's not a working example. I'm trying to make the menu drop down and not stretch on both sides. Look at the 3rd image vs the 2nd. Look at the position of the first item in both comparing to where the selector is. 
BTW - the 3rd image is not a working example, it's a photoshop example. Well... actually paint example :/

Comment: but the codepen link you posted works for me, and it looks like it is what you want..sorry, I might have missed something.

Comment: @sdfacre - Doesn't the value 'AL' appear above where the word 'state' originally is when you run it? Nevertheless, if it's not so, that's probably a resolution thing. I would like it to always open downwards.

Comment: Yes, it went up when there isn't much room below. So you want it to always open downwards and potentially add scrollbar on the whole screen if there isn't much room?

Comment: @sdfacre - The selector has a scrollbar of its own so it's fine. I just need to make sure it opens downwards always.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the dropdown menu went up because there isn't enough space in the lower part. In case you still want it to stay there, you need either to reduce the size of the dropdown to show less options, or increase the height of the full document. Are you ok with the suggestions? If yes, let me know if you need a demo.

Comment: @sdfacre - thanks for your comment. Actually, I have plenty of space in the lower part of the document because the select widget is on the top of the document. I would like to enforce it to drop down always.